# How do you download an english version of Foxmail, and get POP to work?

Tags: email-client, localization

I keep uninstalling and reinstalling e-mail client  foxmail. I was at least able to download Foxmail on Windows 10, but when it opens it is in Chinese, I asked someone to read it for me and used the correct POP ports but it still does not work. The only progress I made was uninstalling the bugged version and getting the software reinstalled. But I still can't get through the steps to get POP working, anyone has a screenshot instruction book? At least on how to translate it, because it is an app and there is no translator.
foxmail.en.lo4d.com/windows 
Says English version, for window 10 but something about it changed it use to work on my computer two years ago but it got bugged somehow and I had to uninstall it to even get it reinstalled

Comment: Are you using the correct version? Have you tried this URL? https://www.foxmail.com/win/en/

Comment: pretty much the same thing it says chinese I can't read, but we use it at my work, and it has been bugged for some time, now I want to go back to it because it's how they manage their business signature files, but it does not allow me to go through all the steps, I hit enter after I enter the server ports and the username and password, because that shouldbe the hot key and i can't read the Chinese, but it checks green and then takes me back to the setup menue.

Comment: Have you got Chinese installed on your PC? Have you tried removing that language pack?

Comment: I have never heard of doing that but I will check to see maybe that is it, good tip...

Comment: Nope I just changed it to US English ><

Comment: If that has solved your problem please post it as an answer.